# trim() in Symfony with APY DataGridBundle

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, datagrid, twig

I'm having some difficulty stripping blank spaces off the end of an input in a form that uses the APY Data Grid bundle.  My suspicions are that this might not be possible without cracking the source code, but I'd love a second opinion and possibly some ideas for a workaround.  Quite simply the search provides no results if an extra blank character is added to the search, so I need to trim it before it hits the query.

Typically trim works fine in twig, like so:

```
{{ 'foo'|trim  }}
```

However this, which uses the above mentioned datagrid, does not

```
{{ filterColumn(grid, 'foo'|trim) }
```

I've tried to handle it in the entity (the way APY works is that it takes the item directly from the entity to the twig), but that didn't work.  Digging through the vendor files to find how the code takes a filter string and convert to a query, and there does not appear to be anywhere to edit the string anywhere along the way.

I'm looking for alternate solutions, such as using javascript to trim the variable before it gets posted (it's not a huge issue regarding the problems of javascript being required; it's for an internal app, and all users here have it installed).  However, this too is proving difficult.   I've been attempting something like this:  [updating for better code]

```
var oldValue = document.forms[0].querySelector('input[id$="foo__query__from"]').value;
var newValue = oldValue.trim();
document.forms[0].querySelector('input[id$="foo__query__from"]').value = newValue;
```

However it still seems to be having the same problem.  The issue is it seems to be only possible to deal with by modifying the vendor files, which a) I'm loathe to do, and b) won't work anyway, as they don't get deployed in the same way.

Note that it is difficult to call in the actual form prior to processing;  there are no typical form files (e.g. formbuilder) being used by APY.  All that is available to me is `{{ filterColumn(grid, 'foo') }`

Solutions/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to wrap the var into parantheses `{{ filterColumn(grid, (foo|trim)) }}`

Comment: @DarkBee thanks for the idea, however this way it did not recognize the variable at all.   I tried with `{{ filterColumn(grid, ('foo'|trim)) }} ` which enabled the page to come back up again, however it had the same result of not stripping blank spaces from the search

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a temporary variable: `{% set variable = 'variable'|trim %}` and then passing that to filterColumn?

Comment: @dbrumann thanks for the suggestion, however it has the same result

Comment: I had a hunch that you might have to use [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html), so I checked out the bundle to get a closer look at filterColumn, but [I can't seem to find it](https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filterColumn&type=) and there's no reference to it in the [TwigExtension](https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Twig/DataGridExtension.php). Could you maybe expand the snippet from your view?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the bundle myself (still doing so), but ran into the same problem.  The view is pretty much exactly what I gave.  I am trying to hack it with js at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time revisited this, and came up with a javascript solution.  Using this took care of the problem, and worked globally for all forms within the application.

```
   $('form').submit(function(){
        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        });
    });
```